# How to make parallax effect with videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax

I am searching for plugins for video parallax effect.I have 4 videos using those i want make parallax effect.Is this possible ? Can anyone suggest me one plugin.

Comment: have you try google?

Comment: i searched but did't get any solution

Comment: Try something and if you stuck somewhere, then ask here because Stackoverflow is a QA website.Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

you can use STELLAR.JS

you can use this link for information regarding stellar.js and how it works

http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/

Comment: i need for videos parallax effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/charlmert/vuetify-video-parallax

This will require that you create a vuejs project.
If you are using vuejs you can use that plugin.